# How to stop function recursion

Tags: javascript

I have a recursive function that call itself. But I want to stop it at a certain situation, something like break, of course it's not a loop so i can't use break. Is there any method? Thank you

Function here, you may see a break, that's when i want to stop the function recall. Thank you!

```
function generateParseTree(parsingArray, left, right, rootIndex) {
    probability *= parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex].prob;
    if (!parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex]['divide']) {
        if (left == parsingArray.length - 2 && right == parsingArray.length - 1) {
            if (probability > 1e-6) {
                suming ++;
                break;
            }
            return;
        } else {                    
            return;
        }
    }
    generateParseTree(parsingArray, left, parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex]['divide'], parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex]['right1Index']);
    generateParseTree(parsingArray, parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex]['divide'], right, parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex]['right2Index']);
        return;

}
```

**Update**-----------------------------------

Sorry my logic is a little mess, the function has been called many times and in each recursion there may be a situation that could be break. What I want is that the first time it reach the stop situation, all the recursion stoped.

**Solution**-----------------------------------

I have use try catch to implement my design, the `break` is replaced with a `throw "flag"`, this way, when i catch the throwed flag, i could break the loop that first call this function.

Thank you all!

Comment: try to use return???

Comment: to get out of a function, simply use `return` just like you did in other palces.

Comment: Your syntax is not highlighted, problem is not really isolated and the code isn't useful to completely reproduce your issue. I tried to improve it in an edit but failed - please improve your question.

Comment: Is what you're _actually_ asking here: "How do I `break` out of nested recursion?"

Comment: @Burki Since he is calling the function twice on each loop, return won't solve the issue and the second function still will be called.

Comment: thank you all, since i do have call this function many times, i want not only stop the current call but all calls. I think simply return won't stop other calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have returns in the code I'm assuming you know that you can just return from the function at that point.

You could return with a value that means something somewhere else.

The functionality that you want is almost (or is) a goto.

So, since exceptions run very similarly to gotos you could implement the method something like the following by throwing an exception when the thing occurs.

```
function generateParseTree(parsingArray, left, right, rootIndex) {
   try
    {
        probability *= parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex].prob;
        if (!parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex]['divide']) {
            if (left == parsingArray.length - 2 && right == parsingArray.length - 1) {
                if (probability > 1e-6) {
                    suming ++;
                    throw "this thing is done";
                }
                return;
            } else {                    
                return;
            }
        }
        generateParseTree(parsingArray, left, parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex]['divide'], parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex]['right1Index']);
        generateParseTree(parsingArray, parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex]['divide'], right, parsingArray[left][right][rootIndex]['right2Index']);
        return;
      }
      catch (err)
      {
           console.log(err); // "this thing is done"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, try catch do fit my purpose. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

can't  you just `return` from the place you'd place `break`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to return a value which indicates to continue or not. At the point where you call the function again, just check the returned value before continuing.

```
<script>
function f(){
  // your code here
  if(breakTheCode){
    return -1;
  }
  if(f()==-1){ // recursion
    return -1;
  }
  return 1;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use return instead break?

Answer (score 0):

Normally if u just write `return` it should break out of the function and returns an `undefined` object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'return' instead of 'break'